# Getting an error as Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

While i am trying to assign string which is "===" to cell in VBA , why getting Application-defined or object-defined error.

This is code snippet i have implemented

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "==="
End Sub
```

Cell R1C1 should be filled by string "===" after executing **ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "==="**. But it is not happening

Can anyone tell me reason , why am not able to assign "===" to cell in VBA ?

Comment: you need something in front of it such as "'===" ,apostrophe

Comment: Because "===" assigns === not the string "===".  To Assign the string '"==="' you will need to use """===""".

Comment: What happens when you try to enter that same text manually into a cell?  That should give you an idea of what the problem is...

Comment: If you want excel to treat is as a string, you need to precede it with a single quote: `"'==="`, or format your cell as text. Otherwise, excel will treat it as an invalid formula. Hence the application-defined error. You can also enter `"=""==="""`, which will become the formula `="==="` in the cell.